# Help with a paper about tensors

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

I came across something in a paper I am not able to understand jet. Unfortunately the author is kind of short with explanations. Maybe someone here can help me to understand this.

> $M^d  \in \mathfrak{R}^{n_1 \times n_2 \times \cdots \times n_d}$ is a $d$-$th$ order tensor with $n_1 \leq n_2 \leq \cdots \leq n_d$.
>
> Rewrite $M^d$ as $(d-1)$-$th$ order tensor $M^{d-1}$ by combing its first and last components into one, and place the combined component into the last one in $M^{d-1}$, i.e.,
>
> $$ M^d_{i_1 ,i_2 , ...,i_d} = M^{d-1}_{i_2 ,i_3 , ...,i_{d-1},(i_1 -1)n_d + i_d},   \forall 1 \leq i_1 \leq n_1, ...,1 \leq i_d \leq n_d$$

First I was thinking about tensor relaxation, but this reduces the rank by 2. And the hole place in last component wont make any sense to me. And if for all $1 \leq i_1 \leq n_1$ and $1 \leq i_d \leq n_d$ the combined component is placed in the last one this would mean by my understanding the last component is $n_1 n_d$ long.

Could someone maybe show me this by a random 4-$th$ order tensor, how to reduce it to a 3-$rd$ order tensor?

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:
The paper defines a tensor as follow

> Consider the following multi-linear unction
>
> $$F(x^1,x^2,...,x^d) = \underset{1 \leq i_1 \leq n_1, 1\leq i_2 \leq n_2 , ... , 1\leq i_d \leq n_d}{\sum}a_{i_1 i_2 ... i_d}x_{i_1}^1x_{i_2}^2\cdots x_{i_d}^d,$$
>
> where $x^k \in \mathfrak{R}^{n_k}, k =1,2,...,d$. In the shorthand notation we shall denote $M = (a_{i_1 i_2 ... i_d}) \in \mathfrak{R}^{n_1 \times n_2 \times \cdots \times n_d}$ to b a $d$-th order tensor.

$\\$

EDIT 2: $\\$

I am still confused trying to imagine a tensors look by this method.
Since $M^d  \in \mathfrak{R}^{n_1 \times n_2 \times \cdots \times n_d}$ and $n_1 \leq n_2 \leq \cdots \leq n_d$. Let’s assume I have a $M_{2,3,4,5}$ tensor. The resulting tensor would be $M_{3,4,10}$.

But how to respahe a tensor like this:

$$ M_{:,:,1,1} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6
\end{array} \right) ; \ \ \
M_{:,:,2,1} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
7 & 8 & 9\\
10 & 11 & 12
\end{array} \right) ; \ \ \ ... \\
M_{:,:,1,2} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
25 & 26 & 27\\
28 & 29 & 30
\end{array} \right) ; \ \ \ 
M_{:,:,2,2} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
30 & 31 & 32\\
33 & 34 & 35
\end{array} \right) ; \ \ \ ... \\
...
$$

into a $3 \times 4 \times 10$-Form? A part of the $M_{2,3,4,5}$ tensor is shown above. It's just counting up, the dots represent the rest.

Comment: What definition of a tensor is used. Is a matrix also a tensor of order 2. What would the reduction of a matrix look like?

Comment: I added the used definition of a tensor. A matrix is also a tensor of order 2. I dont know how a reduction of a matrix would look like, there are no information whatsoever in this paper.

Comment: I think reduction for matrices means to construct a $1$ row vector by writing all the rows consecutively in one row.

Comment: Ok. But the paper mentions the reduction for any given order $d$. I still wonder how this is done for an order of 4 or higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if N is the new $3\times 4\times  10$ tensor we have $N_{1,1,1}=M_{1,1,1,1}\ N_{1,1,2}=M_{1,1,1,2}\ N_{1,1,3}=M_{1,1,1,3}\ N_{1,1,4}=M_{1,1,1,4}\ N_{1,1,5}=M_{1,1,1,5}\ N_{1,1,6}=M_{2,1,1,1}\ N_{1,1,7}=M_{2,1,1,2}\ N_{1,1,8}=M_{2,1,1,3}\ N_{1,1,9}=M_{2,1,1,4}\ N_{1,1,10}=M_{2,1,1,5}$
and
$N_{2,1,1}=M_{1,2,1,1}\ N_{2,1,2}=M_{1,2,1,2}\ N_{2,1,3}=M_{1,2,1,3}\ N_{2,1,4}=M_{1,2,1,4}\ N_{2,1,5}=M_{1,2,1,5}\ N_{2,1,6}=M_{2,2,1,1}\ N_{2,1,7}=M_{2,2,1,2}\ N_{2,1,8}=M_{2,2,1,3}\ N_{2,1,9}=M_{2,2,1,4}\ N_{2,1,10}=M_{2,2,1,5}$
and
$N_{3,1,1}=M_{1,3,1,1}\ N_{3,1,2}=M_{1,3,1,2}\ N_{3,1,3}=M_{1,3,1,3}\ N_{3,1,4}=M_{1,3,1,4}\ N_{3,1,5}=M_{1,3,1,5}\ N_{3,1,6}=M_{2,3,1,1}\ N_{3,1,7}=M_{2,3,1,2}\ N_{3,1,8}=M_{2,3,1,3}\ N_{3,1,9}=M_{2,3,1,4}\ N_{3,1,10}=M_{2,3,1,5}$
And I hope you can continue here (if you please you could raise my reputation by checking my answer as accepted)

Answer (score 1):

Let $M_{ijkl}$ be a degree 4 tensor. Then $M_{jkl1}$ is a degree 3 tensor, just like $M_{jkl2},M_{jkl3}, \ldots,M_{jkln_l}$. Now glue these 3-tensors together by ranging them side by side (like in the matrix case), then we get a new tensor $N_{k,l,m}$ where $m$ takes the successive values 
$\underbrace{\overbrace{1,2,\ldots,n_l}^{n_l \text{ items}},\overbrace{n_l+1,n_l+2,\ldots,n_l+n_l}^{n_l \text{ items}},\ldots,\overbrace{n_l(n_i-1)+1,n_l(n_i-1)+2,\ldots,n_ln_i}^{n_l \text{ items}}}_{n_i\text{ groups of $n_l$ items}}.$
Whence the sequence $(i_1 -1)n_d + i_d$ in the formula of the paper. This is essensially a very old programming trick to manipulate tables in a programming language that only admit linear arrays: If $M_{ij}$ is a $4 \times 6$ matrix it would be converted in a length $24$ array $A$ where the element $M_{ij}$ is stored in $A_{6*(i-1)+j}$

Comment: First, thank you for your answer and effort. And sorry for the late response. I edit my question because I am still confused.

Comment: Your example has me completely lost. You give me a $3\times 2\times 2\times 2$ tensor and you want to make $3\times 4$ tensor?

Comment: I was kind of sloppy explaining what I meant, I hope I could clarify it now.